# Ubuntu 15.10 lib ssl issue

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt-get, apt, ubuntu-15.10

I was using NCL 6.3.0 version successfully, however recently i updated my Ubuntu to version 15.10 from 15.01 and my NCL run gives and error as following.

"ncl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

i tried searching for libssl.so.0.9.8 but it is obsolete and not available, and my libssl is updated to libssl1.0.

Please help me to tackle and this problem so that i cannot start running NCl again.

I tried 
Try

`sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8`

but it gives error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl0.9.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libssl0.9.8:i386
```

further I try

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386
```

but again I get the error

```
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl0.9.8:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libssl0.9.8

I already tried all this , but this is not working.

E: Package 'libssl0.9.8:i386' has no installation candidate

E: Package 'libssl0.9.8' has no installation candidate
```

any solutions ?